# Web2Py - configure a scheduler

Tags: python, web2py, scheduler

I have an application written in Web2Py that contains some modules. I need to call some functions out of a module on a periodic basis, say once daily. I have been trying to get a scheduler working for that purpose but am not sure how to get it working properly. I have referred to [this](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#web2py-Scheduler) and [this](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/2037/create-and-run-web2py-scheduler) to get started.

I have got a `scheduler.py` class in the models directory, which contains code like this:

```
from gluon.scheduler import Scheduler
from Module1 import Module1

def daily_task():
module1 = Module1()
module1.action1(arg1, arg2, arg3)

daily_task_scheduler = Scheduler(db, tasks=dict(my_daily_task=daily_task))
```

In `default.py` I have following code for the scheduler:

```
def daily_periodic_task():
daily_task_scheduler.queue_task('daily_running_task', repeats=0, period=60)
```

[for testing I am running it after 60 seconds, otherwise for daily I plan to use `period=86400`]

In my `Module1.py` class, I have this kind of code:

```
   def action1(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    for row in db().select(db.table1.ALL):
        row.processed = 'processed'
        row.update_record()
```

One of the issues I am facing is that I don't understand clearly how to make this scheduler work to automatically handle the execution of `action1` on daily basis.
When I launch my application using syntax similar to: `python web2py.py -K my_app` it shows this in the console: 
`web2py Web Framework
Created by Massimo Di Pierro, Copyright 2007-2015
Version 2.11.2-stable+timestamp.2015.05.30.16.33.24
Database drivers available: sqlite3, imaplib, pyodbc, pymysql, pg8000
starting single-scheduler for "my_app"...`

However, when I see the browser at: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/default/daily_periodic_task

I just see "None" as text displayed on the screen and I don't see any changes produced by the scheduled task in my database table.

While when I see the browser at: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/default/index

I get an error stating `This web page is not available`, basically indicating my application never got started.

When I start my application normally using `python web2py.py` my application loads fine but I don't see any changes produced by the scheduled task in my database table.

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here and how to properly use the scheduler with Web2Py. Basically, I need to know how can I start my application normally **alongwith** the scheduled tasks properly running in background.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `python web2py.py` starts the built-in web server, enabling web2py to respond to HTTP requests (i.e., serving web pages to a browser). This has nothing to do with the scheduler and will not result in any scheduled tasks being run.

To run scheduled tasks, you must start one or more background workers via:

```
python web2py.py -K myapp
```

The above does not start the built-in web server and therefore does not enable you to visit web pages. It simply starts a worker process that will be available to execute scheduled tasks.

Also, note that the above does not actually result in any tasks being scheduled. To schedule a task, you must insert a record in the `db.scheduler_task` table, which you can do via any of the usual methods of inserting records (including using `appadmin`) or programmatically via the `scheduler.queue_task` method (which is what you use in your `daily_periodic_task` action).

Note, you can simultaneously start the built-in web server and a scheduler worker process via:

```
python web2py.py -a yourpassword -K myapp -X
```

So, to schedule a daily task and have it actually executed, you need to (a) start a scheduler worker and (b) schedule the task. You can schedule the task by visiting your `daily_periodic_task` action, but note that you only need to visit that action once, as once the task has been scheduled, it remains in effect indefinitely (given that you have set `repeats=0`).

If the task does not appear to be working, it is possible there is something wrong with the task itself that is resulting in an error.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the concepts for me Anthony. I understand it better now. But, when I am retrying this, I am getting this error in the browser: `<class 'gluon.contrib.pymysql.err.ProgrammingError'> (1146, u"Table 'my_db_name.scheduler_task' doesn't exist")`. I actually, had these tables generated before somehow, but I accidentally dropped them and they are not getting regenerated. In the console, I keep seeing these kind of messages `Error retrieving status` `ERROR:web2py.scheduler.W-MSR-1M#12188:    error popping tasks`. Any idea how I might be able to resolve this?

Comment: I have been able to identify the root cause of the errors in my case by following the advice specified in [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.web2py/131002). Basically, I did this: "1. make sure no *_scheduler_*.table files are in the databases/* folder
2. make a request to create the tables.... appname/appadmin/index is fine to check if the tables are there or not." But, Anthony your answer set me in the right direction and resolved the queries I originally specified in my question :-)

Comment: For others' reference, I found this really useful [video](https://vimeo.com/27478796) as well regarding usage of scheduler that helped me resolve some other issues that I came across.

Comment: Can you explain what myapp in this case is?

Comment: `myapp` is the name of the web2py app (i.e., the name of its folder within the web2py /applications folder).